# inline ng-template without script tags?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to create inline templates without a `<script>` tag?

My problem is that our widget framework removes `<script>` tags from content, before we can parse them as Angular. So when the app is bootstrapped, the inline templates are not found and ajax requests are made for them, returning 404.

I know most other directives can be used in tag or attribute form, but I have not had any luck trying `<ng-template id="foo">` instead of `<script type="text/ng-template" id="foo">`